# having trouble understanding CASE WHEN statement in SQL

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT    state, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN elevation >= 2000 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as count_high_elevation_aiports 
FROM airports 
GROUP BY state;
```

> In the above statement, what is the THEN 1 and what does '1' signify?
>   How does that value '1' after THEN affect the output?

Answer (score 2):

First, note that these three expressions are equivent:

```
CASE WHEN elevation >= 2000 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END
IF(elevation >= 2000, 1, NULL)
((elevation >= 2000) OR NULL)
```

If elevation >= 2000, the expression evaluates as "1", otherwise the expression evaluates as `NULL`.

"1" is conventionally used as boolean true, and you could substitute the MySQL literal `TRUE` in the above expressions with equivalent results... but that isn't what the "1" is for, here.

**When used with `COUNT()`, in cases like this, the only real significance of `1` is that it is not `NULL`.**

This is important, because -- contrary to popular belief -- **`COUNT()` does not count rows.  It counts values.**

What's the difference?  `NULL` is not technically a value.  Instead, it is a marker that signifies the *absence* of a value, thus `COUNT(expr)` only counts rows where *expr* is not null.

By using an expression like the one here, you're asking the server to count the rows with elevation => 2000, and you do this by giving `COUNT()` a `NULL` for rows you want not to be counted... and a non-null value for rows you do.

[Aggregate (`GROUP BY`) functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html) operate on *values* -- and `NULL`, again, is not a value in this sense.

Another aggregate function that makes this rationale perhaps even more clear is `AVG()`.  If you had 3 rows... with values 5, `NULL`, and 10... what's the average?  If you said 7.5, that's correct: the average of these 3 rows is (5 + 10) ÷ 2 = 5 because the 3 rows have only two values.  `NULL` is not 0, otherwise the average would be (5 + 0 + 10) ÷ 3 = 5, which it is not.

So, that's how and why this works.

> How does that value '1' after `THEN` affect the output?

It really doesn't. You could just as easily have said `COUNT(CASE WHEN elevation >= 2000 THEN 'cat videos are funny' ELSE NULL END)` because, just like the literal `1`, the literal string `'cat videos are funny'` is also not null, and non-null values -- anything not null -- is what count will count.

A novice might try to accomplish this task with `COUNT(elevation >= 2000)`, but that gives the wrong answer, because the 0 (false) for rows where elevation is < 2000 is not null, so these rows would still be counted.

You may then ask, "why not just use `COUNT(*) ... WHERE elevation >= 2000`?"  Good question.  The reasons vary, but if you `GROUP BY state` and there are states with no rows matching `WHERE`, those states would be entirely eliminated from the results, which is often not what you want.  This query includes them, with a count of zero.

---

Note that `((elevation >= 2000) OR NULL)`, the third example expression at the top, doesn't actually need the parentheses. I included them because this form is not necessarilly intuitive at first glance. The natural precedence of operations will cause this to be evaluated correctly if written simply `elevation >= 2000 OR NULL`.  This expression is equivalent to the other two because `elevation >= 2000` first evaluates to 1 if true, 0 if false, or `NULL` if elevation is null.  Then the lower-precedence `OR` is evaluated, and you get one of these: `1 OR NULL => 1` ... `0 OR NULL => NULL` ... `NULL OR NULL => NULL`... and you may actually be awarded a SQL wizard badge by the elders of the Internet at the point when writing queries with `COUNT(elevation >= 2000 OR NULL)` comes naturally to you.

Answer (score 1):

Query will simply return **1 if `elevation`** is `>` or `=` 2000, else it will return **`NULL`** (this is use full for **boolean** representation of field because **NULL** represents **0**),
Now returned value will be set into **`count_high_elevation_airports`**.

Comment: `NULL` does not "represent 0" here, and 1 being equivalent to boolean true is only coincidental.  I believe you may have overlooked the fact that an aggregate function is being used here, or perhaps one of the implications this entails.